# Scripts for printer configuration mono / color - Windows 7

Tags: printing

I've been working on this for some time and nearly got it working. Nearly....

I am creating a script under Win7 Ent that's adding 2 network printers (no printer server - just via IP address). For each printer I want it to create a colour and mono queue - so 4 printer queues in total.

Adding works fine with those commands:

```
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Operators_Color"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Operators_MOno"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Traders_Color"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Traders_MOno"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116mono
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116color
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118mono
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118color

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Operators_Color"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Operators_MOno"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Traders_Color"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "XXX_Traders_MOno"
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116mono
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116color
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118mono
cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -d -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118color

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -a -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116mono -h XXX.XXX.XXX.116 -o raw -n 9100

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -a -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116color -h XXX.XXX.XXX.116 -o raw -n 9100

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -a -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118mono -h XXX.XXX.XXX.118 -o raw -n 9100

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnport.vbs" -a -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118color -h XXX.XXX.XXX.118 -o raw -n 9100

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prndrvr.vbs" -a -m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -i C:\XXXXX\Drivers\hpzius23.inf

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "XXX_Traders_Color" -m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116color

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "XXX_Traders_MOno" -m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.116mono

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "XXX_Operators_Color" -m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118color

cscript "C:\XXXXX\Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "XXX_Operators_MOno" -m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -r IP_XXX.XXX.XXX.118mono'
```

I hit a wall when trying to set the queues with color / mono setting.

Tried two methods:

1. Via Powershell Set-PrintConfiguration command:

   Set-PrintConfiguration –PrinterName "XXX_Traders_Color" -Color "1"

   Set-PrintConfiguration –PrinterName "XXX_Traders_MOno" -Color "0"

   Set-PrintConfiguration –PrinterName "XXX_Operators_Color" -Color "1"

   Set-PrintConfiguration –PrinterName "XXX_Operators_MOno" -Color "0"

I'm getting below (guessing this is not a command present in Win 7 powershell):

The term 'Set-PrintConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.

2. I tried using the RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry commands to

   - export printer configuration with changed mono / color setting (works fine)
     RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "XXX_Operators_MOno" /a "c:\temp\Mirek1.dat" d g
   - import the file created above into new queue:
     RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "NewXXX_Operators_MOno" /a "c:\temp\Mirek1.dat"

But the second command doesn't seem to cause the queue to adjust mono / color setting that was exported in the first instance.

I wonder if anyone here has struggled with similar headache?

Any help much appreciated..

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work by using the `u` switch (instead of `d g`).  That exports "User DevMode":

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "XXX_Operators_MOno" /a "c:\temp\Mirek1.dat" u
```